# To turn a ratioed circuit into non-ratioed circuit, what should be the transistor sizes for proper operation of this circuit?

Tags: transistors, flipflop, nmos, latch, pmos

The circuit is at the bottom. I know it is a ratioed circuit however, how can I convert it to a non-ratioed circuit without adding two more PMOS transistors between Vdd and the other PMOSs. Also, what should be the transistor sizing for proper operation?
[image]

Comment: Why can't you change the transistor dimensions? If the dimensions are fixed, why can't you add the extra PMOS transistors? If you want help with transistor sizing then you need to show us the sizes that you are currently using and explain why they are not satisfactory. You need to share your power and timing requirements, as well as the transistor parameters.

Comment: I know by adding two PMOSs to block Vdd, this gets rid of contention. But I also know that by changing the transistor sizes the contention can be removed. I should have asked how sizing the transistors remove could remove the contention. Like what should we consider if we want to go that route?

Comment: Sizing the transistors doesn't eliminate contention, it just ensures that the NMOS transistors win. For the circuit given, you need the PMOS transistors to be weaker than the NMOS transistors.

Comment: Does contention happen on both of the inverters? Is this why we add two more PMOS at the PUN and not one? Also, let's assume that the transistor sizes of all 4 transistors are the same. Is is enough if just increase the size of the NMOSs or is it more complicated than that? One last question, does the contention happen between the NMOS with the S input and the PMOS at the Vdd side? If so, does the same contention happen between the NMOS with the R input and the PMOS on the other side?